# assetic in app/Resources not taking the class

Tags: css, symfony, assetic

I am programming in Symfony2 and I have created in app/Resources/assets directory the folders: css and js, where I have created some css and js files. I have compressed and added them to web folder following instructions in http://symfonybricks.com/es/brick/smart-use-of-assetic-to-compress-javascripts-and-stylesheets. (After executing the following command , they are already created in web folder)

> php app/console assetic:dump

The problem is that when I use in my index.html.twig file (which is in a bundle inside src directory) a class that I have created in my main.css file (in app/Resources/css), it is not taking the style.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The setup that you are using is very common in Symfony application. In fact, is the one used by the [Symfony Demo Application](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-demo) which is an application used to show the recommended way to develop Symfony applications.

Regarding the error that you are facing:

- You say that the `assetic:dump` command correctly generates the files in `web/`. Can you check the contents of those generated files?
- You say that "is not taking the style". can you check with your browser inspector to see if the style is correctly applied but overridden by other styles or if it's indeed not applied by any CSS rule?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have created a blank project using Symfony Demo Application you said and I want to modify it in order to adapt it to my project. I see there is an assets folder in app/Resources directory where there are some css, js and scss (I have never worked with this) files. Do you recomend me to use and modify those files for my new styles or should I place them inside src/(name)bundle/Resources/public/css? And another question, what is the directory AppBundle for? Can I delete it or is it necessary?